# Private method call using delegate

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates, private-members

I am reading *CLR via C#* 4th edition. In the chapter covering delegates (chapter 17), it is written that:

> The `FeedbackToConsole` method is defined as private inside the `Program` type, but the `Counter` method is able to call `Program`’s private method. In this case, you might not expect a problem because both `Counter` and `FeedbackToConsole` are defined in the same type. However, this code would work just fine even if the `Counter` method was defined in another type. In short, it is not a security or accessibility violation for one type to have code that calls another type’s private member via a delegate as long as the delegate object is created by code that has ample security/ accessibility.

I am experimenting with this idea, but I'm not able to call a private method from another type. Here is my code:

```csharp
namespace DelegatesEvents
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Counter(1, 2, new FeedBack(DelegateEventsDemo.FeedBackToConsole));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Counter(int p1, int p2, FeedBack feedBack)
        {
            for (int i = p1; i <= p2; i++)
            {
                if (feedBack != null)
                {
                    feedBack(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace DelegatesEvents
{
    internal delegate void FeedBack(Int32 val);

    public class DelegateEventsDemo
    {
        private static void FeedBackToConsole(Int32 val)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good morning delegates" + val);
        }
    }
}
```

When I declare `FeedBackToConsole` as private, it can not be called in the delegate, as expected if I was trying to call it otherwise.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

In short, it is not a security or accessibility violation for one type to have code that calls another type’s private member via a delegate as long as the delegate object is **created by code that has ample security/accessibility**.

`DelegateEventsDemo` has to create the delegate object. So we add public `GetFeedBackDelegate` method (you can add property as well) which returns the delegate object referencing private method.

```
namespace DelegatesEvents
{
    internal delegate void FeedBack(Int32 val);

    public class DelegateEventsDemo
    {
        private static void FeedBackToConsole(Int32 val)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good morning delegates" + val);
        }

        internal static FeedBack GetFeedBackDelegate()
        {
            return FeedBackToConsole;
        }
    }
}
```

And used by the code:

```
namespace DelegatesEvents
{
    class Program
    {
        public  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Counter(1, 2, DelegateEventsDemo.GetFeedBackDelegate());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Counter(int p1, int p2, FeedBack feedBack)
        {
            for (int i = p1; i <= p2; i++)
            {
                if (feedBack != null)
                {
                    feedBack(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to C#.My doubt is I have already declared delegate as internal and also tested using public based on the statement "delegate object is created by code that has ample security/accessibility".But without creating property or method mentioned above it is not working.Plz clear my doubt.

Comment: @user3611378 Method `DelegateEventsDemo.FeedBackToConsole` is private to `DelegateEventsDemo` class, thus nobody has access to it (we don't consider reflection). But `DelegateEventsDemo` class can create delegate **object** referencing this private method and return it to any other code. Thus that other code has delegate **object** to invoke private method of `DelegateEventsDemo` class.

Answer (score 0):

as Richter and [Ulugbek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803777/ulugbek-umirov) mentioned the code that creates delegate needs to be accessible enough to the method, wrapped by the delegate. Delegate is created within DelegateEventsDemo, that stores referenced FeedBackToConsole method. So everything is fine with enough accessibility.